# While using qr_flutter package Iam getting an error "The argument type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'." for the QrImage()

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, qr-code

While using qr_flutter package Iam getting an error "The argument type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'." for the QrImage()

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;

  const ProfileScreen({Key? key, required this.userId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Your Profile'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            onPressed: () async {
              try {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');
              } catch (e) {
                print('Logout failed: $e');
                // Handle logout failure
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: QrImage(
                data: userId, // Use the provided user ID to generate a unique QR code
                version: QrVersions.auto,
                size: 200.0,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            // Additional user information widgets can be added here
            // For example, you can fetch and display the user's name, email, etc.
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have flutter version " Flutter 3.16.2 ".And dependencies are added in pubspec.yaml file too.

Still get an error like in the image :
[Error Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmzrE.png)

I've changed channel to Beta (Reversed to stable after)
upgraded flutter to latest version
added proper dependencies
tried reopening vscode

Answer (score 1):

[`QrImage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/qr_flutter/latest/qr_flutter/QrImage-class.html) is not a widget. You can see in the documentation that it does not extend the [`Widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html) class. Use [`QRImageView`](https://pub.dev/documentation/qr_flutter/latest/qr_flutter/QrImageView-class.html) to display your QR code in the UI.

```dart
Center(
  child: QrImageView(
    data: userId, // Use the provided user ID to generate a unique QR code
    version: QrVersions.auto,
    size: 200.0,
  ),
),
```