# Why isn't QrImage allowed?

Tags: android, flutter

```
QrImage(
                data: qrData,
                version: QrVersions.auto,
                size: 200.0,
              )
```

I also added the expansion pack to `pubspec.yaml`, but for some reason I got an error. Using `QrImageView` does not suit my purpose. My head is empty.

Continue here "The element type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'." This error appears.

I want to make a QR code appear when I press the button in my code, but it doesn't work. Any further requests please contact me.

```
class QrConfirmationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String qrData;

  QrConfirmationScreen({required this.qrData});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEA7070),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QR 확인'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEA7070),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              '생성된 QR 코드',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (qrData.isNotEmpty)
              QrImage(
                data: qrData,
                version: QrVersions.auto,
                size: 200.0,
              )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While using qr\_flutter package Iam getting an error "The argument type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'." for the QrImage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589369/while-using-qr-flutter-package-iam-getting-an-error-the-argument-type-qrimage)

Answer (score 1):

Please provide next time the exact package name (import "package.name" ) to better understand *your* problem.

Your problem is that QrImage is not a **Widget** and you just need to wrap it into some widget like [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html).

To fix your issue I just wrap it into Container like:

```
 Container(
  child: QrImageView(
    data: qrData, // Here is your QR data
    version: QrVersions.auto,
    size: 200.0,
  ),
),
```